# Selenium and Zapier

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, zapier

I currently have some ad-hoc scripts I run using Selenium to automate browser tasks with sites that do not have an API.

I wish to move this to trigger-based running.

One possible way is do this is to build in these triggers to the scripts, so every x min/seconds, it will check and run if necessary. I have a spare computer that will have this constantly running, but I would prefer to not do it this way.

Is there any way to integrate Selenium and Zapier or complete a similar task by using Zapier triggers?

The script is written in Python.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having windows system you can use Task scheduler. If you are having Linux you can use crontab to schedule tasks.

Assuming you may have windows, You can create .bat file to trigger your selenium (say mytask.bat). Execute the mytask.bat using scheduler.

Start->Control Panel->System and Security->Administrative Tools->Task Scheduler
Action->Create Basic Task->Type a name and Click Next
Follow through the wizard as screen shot given below.[image]